# Add one actionbar for all activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar which has a few buttons; I want to display this ActionBar for all activities.

So, instead of including layout code of this ActionBar for all screens, how can I use it efficiently (in a way that will work in API8)?

Comment: there's this thing called inheritance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) you should read on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one layout xml for your toolbar for example **view_toolbar.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        //...your parameters >

     //...your buttons
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And after then you can include your other layout as is shown in the code below:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/view_toolbar"/>

    //your other views
</RelativeLayout>
```